# How to skip query in column where statement when value is null

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I've got simple table

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../util/database'); 
const Speed = sequelize.define('speed', {
   id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true},
   level: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   ...
})
module.exports = Speed;
```

and query

```
exports.getSpeed = async (req, res, next) => {
   const level = req.body.level
   try {
      const speed = await Speed.findAll({
         where: {level: level, ...}
      });
      res.status(200)
         .json({result: speed})
   }
   catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
   }
}
```

How can I get all results from speed table when `level` from request body is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
exports.getSpeed = async (req, res, next) => {
   const level = req.body.level
   let where = {}; 

   if(level)
      where = { level: level}

   try {
      const speed = await Speed.findAll({
         where
      });
      res.status(200)
         .json({result: speed})
   }
   catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
   }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but I believe there must be another way.. Mather of fact I've got 5 columns in that table like that so the if statement would be just ridiculous. Thanks anyway

Comment: Looks like there is no other way... Thanks